Policy: How to give Google Play subscription credentials with paywalled app for review?
I'm building a React Native app using react-native-iap. Initially, I had a freemium model where a user could use the app for a bit before needing to sign up for a subscription. I'd like to move to a paid only version, where the app is paywalled (via checking the validity of the availablePurchases object) and users subscribe just with their Google Play account via an in app purchase/subscription. There are no credentials or other sign in mechanisms. It’s just through IAP.

In order for us to review your app for compliance with Developer Program policies we will need you to provide valid login credentials for your app, and any other resources needed to review your app.

My app is getting rejected due to not providing app access instructions or login credentials. How can I provide the reviewers with the necessary instructions to work around this?
Would making another Google account that is subscribed work? What instructions do I need to provide to have it work with IAP? I can’t seem to find or understand the testing environment that reviewers use.
